# How can I perform downloads that are intercepted by a virus scanner?

Tags: javascript, html

We create a ZIP file on the server and want to download it as soon as it has been created.
Unfortunately we have no user interaction when the download is ready. Our solution works well in all modern browsers as long as the download is not intercepted by a virus scanner?

```
const downloadFromUrl = (url: string, fileName?: string) => {
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  if (!fileName) {
    fileName =
      url.lastIndexOf('/') >= -1 ? url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')) : '';
  }

  // Without this option, Chrome displays a pop-up warning. 
  // If the download is intercepted by a virus scanner, the HTML page of the intercepted file page
  // will be downloaded instead (bad) and the user will not be able to click on the real download
  // button on the intercepted page.
  a.setAttribute('download', fileName);

  // Firefox also needs a "_blank" target, as it otherwise closes all open websocket connections
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');

  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
};
```

Is there a way to download the file without a popup warning even if the real download link is only on the HTML page delivered by the virus scanner?

Our current solution downloads the html file of the virus scanner.

How can the file be downloaded without a popup warning if the download is intercepted by a virus scanner? How can I display the intercepted HTML page in this case?

Is displaying the link and letting the user click on it really the only option?

Comment: *"Our current solution downloads the html file of the virus scanner."* Why would virus scanners rewrite your download URL? Do you have an example of this, like showing a request of your browser developer tools? A virus scannner running locally will download the file and scan it after the download is finished, not rewrite the URL of the downloaded file before the download has started. Is there a browser plugin that does this or something?